# How do I put a Count and an Assert in this VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, counter, assert, bit, multiplication

I had to put an Assert and a Counter in this VHDL code, to test all the possibilities. It's a 4x4 bit multiplier, but I don't know how I put the Assert and a Counter to test all the possible words.

PS.: The Half-Adder, Full-Adder and 8-Bits Full Adder works.

```
    library IEEE;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

    entity Mult is PORT(
        A: in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        B: in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        S: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));
    end Mult;

    architecture behav_Mult of Mult is
        signal X, Y, Z, K, M, N: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := "00000000";
    begin

    X(0) <= A(0) and B(0);
    X(1) <= A(1) and B(0);
    X(2) <= A(2) and B(0);
    X(3) <= A(3) and B(0);

    Y(1) <= A(0) and B(1);
    Y(2) <= A(1) and B(1);
    Y(3) <= A(2) and B(1);
    Y(4) <= A(3) and B(1);

    Z(2) <= A(0) and B(2);
    Z(3) <= A(1) and B(2);
    Z(4) <= A(2) and B(2);
    Z(5) <= A(3) and B(2);

    K(3) <= A(0) and B(3);
    K(4) <= A(1) and B(3);
    K(5) <= A(2) and B(3);
    K(6) <= A(3) and B(3);

        iFAD0: entity work.FAD7 port map(
            A=>X,
            B=>Y,
            S=>M,
            Ci => '0',
            Co => open);

        iFAD1: entity work.FAD7 port map(
            A=>Z,
            B=>K,
            S=>N,
            Ci=> '0',
            Co => open);

        iFAD2: entity work.FAD7 port map(
            A=> M,
            B=> N,
            S=> S,
            Ci=> '0',
            Co => open);
    end behav_Mult;




    library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity Mult_TB is
end Mult_TB;

architecture TB of Mult_TB is
    signal tA: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal tB: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal tS: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    signal cont: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
begin
    iMult: entity work.Mult port map(
        A=>tA, B=>tB, S=>tS
    );
    tA <= cont (3 downto 0);
    tB <= cont (7 downto 4);
    process
        cont <= cont + 1; 
        wait for 20 ns;
    begin

    end process;
end TB;
```

Comment: I had to put the Assert and Counter in TestBench. Do I have to change anything in the Mult code? Do I have to put anything more in the code (such as a clock, reset)...??

Comment: You already have a counter in the testbench! You can put an assert after `wait for 20 ns;` by which time the multiplier outputs should be stable.